Use openxlsx2 to color specific rows in a vector of indexes
I have a data frame that I want to save into XLSX format using openxlsx2.
This data frame contains entries with specific columns with identical values.
I want to highlight those entries (the whole row) in the output XLSX file, using different fill colors.
I'm not going to go into detail on how I get those entries, but at the end, I end up with a data frame pretty similar to this modified mtcars in the MWE example below:
#load data
data(mtcars)
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
brand_split <- strsplit(mtcars$model, "\\s+")
mtcars$brand <- sapply(brand_split, "[", 1)
#color data frame
color_df <- data.frame(model=c("Mazda RX4","Mazda RX4 Wag","Merc 230","Merc 240D","Merc 280","Merc 280C","Merc 450SE","Merc 450SL","Merc 450SLC","Fiat 128","Fiat X1-9"),
                       color=c("red","red","blue","blue","green","green","yellow","yellow","yellow","purple","purple"))
mtcars <- dplyr::left_join(mtcars, color_df, by="model")
main_cols <- c('model','brand','gear','carb')
other_cols <- names(mtcars)[!(names(mtcars) %in% main_cols)]
mtcars <- mtcars[,c(main_cols, other_cols)]

... which produces:
> mtcars
                 model    brand gear carb  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am  color
1            Mazda RX4    Mazda    4    4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    red
2        Mazda RX4 Wag    Mazda    4    4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    red
3           Datsun 710   Datsun    4    1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1   <NA>
4       Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet    3    1 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0   <NA>
5    Hornet Sportabout   Hornet    3    2 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0   <NA>
6              Valiant  Valiant    3    1 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0   <NA>
7           Duster 360   Duster    3    4 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0   <NA>
8            Merc 240D     Merc    4    2 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0   blue
9             Merc 230     Merc    4    2 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0   blue
10            Merc 280     Merc    4    4 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0  green
...

I want to create an XLSX file with that data frame (minus the color column), in which each row is colored by the color defined in the color column.
I checked different resources, like this and this... but nothing comes close to what I want to do, which seems to me like the easiest and most obvious case.
I found this question, which seems to want to accomplish the same, but they use the outdated openxlsx, not openxlsx2.
I tried looking in the openxlsx2 manual for similar functions, but no success so far.
This is my code so far, to just save the data in XLSX format:
mtcars_wb <- openxlsx2::wb_workbook()
mtcars_wb$add_worksheet(sheet = "mtcars")
mtcars_wb$add_data(sheet = "mtcars", x = mtcars[,-ncol(mtcars)], na.strings = "NA")
#
output_file <- "mtcars_test.xlsx"
openxlsx2::wb_save(mtcars_wb, file = output_file)

... which produces this:

Two problems here:

I am still missing the row colors
The output file opens in a really small window for some reason

For 1, based on the question above that uses openxlsx, I want to do something similar like this (which obviously does not work):
for (color in unique(color_df$color)){
  rows <- which(mtcars$color==color)
  if (length(rows)>0){
    color_style <- openxlsx2::create_style(fontColour = "#000000", fgFill = color)
    mtcars_wb$add_style(sheet = "mtcars", cols = 1:ncol(mtcars), rows = rows, style = color_style, gridExpand = TRUE)
  }
}

For 2 as a bonus, I would like to change the output window size, which I cannot figure out how... maybe something like this (which also does not work)?
options("openxlsx2.outputSize" = <MUCH BIGGER WINDOW SIZE>)

At the end, the output XLSX file should look like:

Thanks!

Regarding the window size request, have a look here. Nothing has changed since, but I might add a PR to make this a little more convenient

Oh there is wb_set_bookview().

Hi @JanMarvin thanks for this comment! I am trying wb_set_bookview but still not sure how to make it work... I do mywb$set_bookview(window_height = 10, window_width = 10), but regardless of the numbers I add, it always opens in full window... which are the units?

The unit is TWIPS a twenties of a point. In the link there's a formula, I'd just toy around a bit until you have what you need. If you overflow (and apparently; haven't checked this myself) underflow, it goes to fullscreen.

I've renamed the data frame to df for simplicity. This gives the output you desire:
packages <- c("openxlsx2", "dplyr")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)

# load data
df <- mtcars
df$model <- rownames(df)
rownames(df) <- NULL
brand_split <- strsplit(df$model, "\\s+")
df$brand <- sapply(brand_split, "[", 1)

# colors
color_df <- data.frame(model=c("Mazda RX4","Mazda RX4 Wag","Merc 230","Merc 240D","Merc 280","Merc 280C","Merc 450SE","Merc 450SL","Merc 450SLC","Fiat 128","Fiat X1-9"),
                       color=c("red","red","blue","blue","green","green","yellow","yellow","yellow","purple","purple"))
df <- left_join(df, color_df, by="model")

# pull out colors, don't want in output.
colors <- df$color
df <- df %>% select(-color)

main_cols <- c('model','brand','gear','carb')
other_cols <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% main_cols)]
df <- df[,c(main_cols, other_cols)]

# WB and WS objects
mywb <- wb_workbook()
mywb$add_worksheet("mysheet")
wb_add_data(mywb, "mysheet", df, dims="A1")

# color the rows
lapply(seq_along(colors),
       function(x) if(!(is.na(colors[x]))) {
         mywb$add_fill("mysheet",
                       dims=paste0("A", x+1, ":", int2col(ncol(df)), x+1),
                       color=wb_color(name=colors[x]))
       }
)

wb_save(mywb, "out.xlsx")


Please don't use write_data() in new code. The function will be deprecated soon.

@JanMarvin, duly noted. I have a significant piece of code that relies on your really nice openxlsx2 package and it turns out that I never used write_data(). I will update my answer.

Here is an option using the add_fill method:
library(openxlsx2)

for (color in unique(mtcars$color[!is.na(mtcars$color)])) {
  rows <- which(mtcars$color %in% color)
  dims <- sapply(rows, \(row) openxlsx2::rowcol_to_dims(
    row + 1,
    seq_len(ncol(mtcars[-ncol(mtcars)])),
    single = TRUE
  ))
  dims <- paste(dims, collapse = ";")
  mtcars_wb$add_fill(
    sheet = "mtcars",
    dims = dims,
    color = openxlsx2::wb_color(color)
  )
}

output_file <- "mtcars_test.xlsx"
openxlsx2::wb_save(mtcars_wb, file = output_file)



I took inspiration from this answer which can be simplified using the development branch of openxlsx2 which allows for non consecutive columns and rows in wb_dims(). This way, creation of dims is a single call: https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/discussions/1043
